# how to set the css left property of a class on the basis of an ID of a tag

Tags: jquery, css

I am actually trying to set the left property of a class on the basis of a li tag id. I am dynamically generating the li tag as below:

**.js**

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
$.each(months, function (i, v) {
    var li = $('<li id="sp_month_' + v + '">' + v + '</li>')
    $('#servicePlanMonths').append(li);
});
```

I am getting the LI tag Id as **sp_month_jan** and so on....

Now using these Id I would like to set the .css left property of another div(this is also generated dynamically as below) to the exact same as it is for each li id. Below is the code for generating another div:

**.js**

```
function DrawSPPriorityTimeLine(curelement, priorityObj) 
{
var priorityMonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var timeFrame = priorityObj.TimeFrames();
var activityTotalMonth = [];
//$this.activityTotalMonth = ko.observableArray([]);

if (timeFrame.trim().length > 0 && timeFrame.trim() != "On-going") {
    var startMonth = jQuery.inArray(timeFrame.split('-')[0].trim(), priorityMonth);
    var endMonth = (timeFrame.split('-').length > 1) ? jQuery.inArray(timeFrame.split('-')[1].trim(), priorityMonth) : startMonth;
} else {
    var startMonth = 0;
    var endMonth = 11;
}

//var temp1 = priorityMonth.slice(startMonth, priorityMonth.length);
//var temp2 = priorityMonth.slice(endMonth, priorityMonth.length);
//priorityMonth = $.merge(temp1, temp2);

var activityMonth = (endMonth - startMonth + 1) * 3 - 2;

for (var j = 0; j <= activityMonth; j++)
    activityTotalMonth.push(j);

$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {
    var div = $('<div>').addClass('counts');        
    $(curelement).find('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
```

}

**.css**

```
.bar-steps .counts {
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    float: left;
    background: #999;
    margin-right: 22px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

The div is generated dynamically and I am appending the class "counts" so that it render the style as well.

The problem is that when these divs(appending class counts) are generated, the divs are not align to the li tag.

With the help of the Li tag, i have the month name displayed horizontally which is perfectly working. Now I am trying aligning the left property of the other div (uses the class "counts")which will start generating the divs from the same place where the li text(eg month name Feb) is displayed.

Comment: where you are calling DrawSPPriorityTimeLine. try to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed further and got the resolution. Below is the result that I was expecting before:

```
// This variable will contain the left position value for the starting month in the priority's time frame 
var monthLeftPosition = $('#servicePlanMonths').find('#sp_month_' + startingMonth).position().left;

$(curelement).find('.bar-steps').offset({ left: monthLeftPosition });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following options:

1. `document.getElementById("myBtn").style.left = "100px";`
2. `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginLeft = "50px";`